# Protocol oriented programming and introduction of additional properties

Tags: swift

I started using POP couple months ago and I really like the premise. Despite all that it allows us to do I feel that inability to introduce new properties really cripples it. I find that in real world situations I often need to introduce one or more property that the extension needs to do what it is intended to do. Most recent example is this:

I have extension to UIView that renders special kind of border. I do this by creating new CALayer and adding it as sublayer to view. Everything worked fine until I noticed that when view's bounds change, I am stuck with old border. To remedy this, I wanted to store the border layer into property and when layout changed I would remove old border layer and create new one. But since protocols can't add properties directly, I had to use subclass.

I am not really interested how to handle situation above as I omitted some details that might render your improvements unusable. I would like to know if this is something we have to live with and just revert to subclasses or I am missing something and was can somehow overcome it.

I know that protocols can define properties that classes implementing it need to define as well, but this is fairly limiting too. In example above, I wanted to extend functionality of UIView, not some subclass of UIView, so that it can be used in any view

Comment: I don't think anyone knows how to describe how/when/where/what to use Protocols for without awkward avoidance of conflict. The only reasoning (for use) that's well articulated is the "why". This has been spurious claims of readability, flexibility, ease of use and creation, maintainability etc. All nebulous claims applied to every single new programming paradigm since... forever. It's great in theory, but it's only been explained theoretically, too.

Comment: On top of this, Apple has a poor run of not eating it's own dog food, when it comes to Swift. Remember the response when it was discovered almost no Apple apps are made with Swift, yet they were preaching it for everyone else? I think, contrary to their hardware cycles, any claims Apple makes about software should wait 2 or 3 generations before being considered legitimate. They don't make a whisper about their new hardware's abilities until its released and provable. This policy is not applied to software and frameworks, where they proclaim in the hope of attaining uptake. They're burnt.

Comment: Really? I thought swift was more popular than "almost no apps are made with swift". I just don't see a point of using obj-c unless you really have to. I made a switch to swift around 1.3 and never regret that decision. I even went back and rewrote some of older apps to pure (well, as pure as you can) swift. Now when I do need to get back to older project done in obj-c I do it with disgust on my face

Comment: TL;DR - Stick to OOP and MVC until Apple positively proves the processes, performance and practicalities of POP they've so pompously proclaimed in their pretty parades and perfectly packaged presentations for protocols's potential and promise as a paradigm of app programming.

Comment: I'm not suggesting Obj-C, I'm suggesting using Swift as it fits to UIKit and the Apple frameworks of the now, not the potential or promise of whatever POP will become as a paradigm and is pitched as for the future.

Comment: I know, I was just surprised by the claim that swift apps are still rare. I never did research and I expected most people would switch long time ago

Comment: You're missing the context of my statement. I'm not talking about independent or 3rd party devs. It was discovered (early this year) that almost nothing made by Apple used Swift. https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/is-apple-using-swift-4a6c80f74599#.rb9t2ocbn

Comment: Ah, I get it now, thanks for clarification

Comment: No worries. Personally, I find Swift (except for reading and deciphering optionals) to be more comprehensible than Objective-C. But it's also made me better at reading Objective-C.

Comment: Is there anyway I can help you with a way to get genuine attention for this question? I'm more than a little curious about this, too.

Comment: I have no idea :)

Answer (score -1):

My cheeky answer:

Protocol Oriented Programming is a poor man's multiple inheritance for an OOP language that's not got it.

So if you find you don't have something-or-another you need in your hierarchy, just make another protocol, and conform the necessary objects to it.

Composition over inheritance?

Or inherited composition?

Probably doesn't even matter.

;)

Whatever works.